# CSS break line in three parts if not fit to window/parent size

Tags: css, html

```
Period: From May 2013 To April 2013
```

How can I do that text to display on one or auto breaks to three lines if text not fit to window/parent size

```
Period:
From May 2013
To April 2013
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/PkXc9/)

## Conclusion

Its not possible to do with pure CSS

My simple solution - JS and its update one time at load

[FIDDLE with JS](http://jsfiddle.net/PkXc9/1/)

If someone can do better - please provide demo

Comment: would you do like this through javascript/jquery or using css only? also, it's better if you provide an example through jsfiddle.net, jsbin.com which has outer content etc.

Comment: css only better, JS not convenient

Comment: Is it ok to have two lines "Period: From May 2013" and "To April 2013" if the window can contain that, or do you want to avoid it? Also, the "to" date is before the "from" date, is that right?

Comment: as far as i know, it is not possible to count characters through css. if you're able to change markup, you can add `<br/>`s manually. Otherwise, you have to go for javascript/jquery method to break lines.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the individual 'parts' in a span tag.

http://jsfiddle.net/HwZ23/1/

```
<p class="period"><span>Period:</span> <span>From May 2013</span> <span>To April 2013</span></p>



.period span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I should note, this will 'break' at the correct place, however, it won't always format into three lines dependent on screen resolution. For that, you would need to use media queries.
With media queries, at the desired resolution, you would declare the .period span as display: block

Comment: Its very close! But, when I resize frame, string split to 2 lines, if I continue resize - then to 3 lines, but I need only 1 line or 3, without 2 lines stage

Comment: That's pretty difficult to achieve without using media queries. This is a pretty good article that will explain what they are and how to use them: http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/19/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/

Answer (score 0):

You can also force this using non breaking spaces:

```
Period:
From&nbsp;May&nbsp;2013
To&nbsp;April&nbsp;2013
```

Comment: Yes, but note that this will change the actual content of the page. For instance, the user will no longer be able to perform a search for the text "From May".

Answer (score 0):

```
<div><span>Period:</span><span>From May 2012</span><span>To May 2013 </span>

div span {
    display: inline-block;
}
```